# Scroll down to <main> on button click jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I am looking for a way to add a scrolling effect to a button using jQuery. Basically I have a div that holds the button like that NOTE: button below the p and that div is at the very top of the page so its the first thing the user sees once he enters the page:

```
<div id="showcase" class="body body-default">
  <div class="home-showcase-image">
    <div class="content-wrap">
      <h1 class="h-home-header">Welcome</h1>
      <p>
        Corporis justo torquent, gravida phasellus, nec lacinia. Cras ut, viverra suspendisse. Netus sem, placerat turpis, qui ut. A in. Lacinia wisi nobis, nulla purus luctus, id mi fermentum. Et suscipit, nec maecenas, donec risus.
        Corporis justo torquent, gravida phasellus, nec lacinia. Cras ut, viverra suspendisse. Netus sem, placerat turpis, qui ut. A in. Lacinia wisi nobis, nulla purus luctus, id mi fermentum. Et suscipit, nec maecenas, donec risus.
      </p>
      <button type="button" id="readMoreButton" class="read-more-button">Read More</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have several sections in a main like that:

```
<main id="main">
  <!--Section A-->
  <section id="section-a" class="grid">
    //content
  </section>

  <!--Section B-->
  <section id="section-b" class="grid section-b-home-allign">
    //content
  </section>
</main>
```

Basically on click I want the page to scroll down to the main tag. I tried something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#readMoreButton").click(function () {
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $("#main").offset().top
    });
  });
</script>
```

However, nothing happens. Once I click the button it stays at the top of the page. What am I missing?

Any help would appropriated. Thanks.

Comment: Any messages in the error console?

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working fine. Please check this code. possibly you forgot to add Jquery min file.

```js
$("#readMoreButton").click(function () {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#main").offset().top
    });
});
```

```css
#showcase{
  min-height: 700px;
}
.grid{
  min-height:600px;
  margin: 15px 0;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="showcase" class="body body-default">
            <div class="home-showcase-image">
                <div class="content-wrap">
                    <h1 class="h-home-header">Welcome</h1>

                    <p>
                        Corporis justo torquent, gravida phasellus, nec lacinia. Cras ut, viverra suspendisse. Netus sem,
                        placerat turpis, qui ut. A in. Lacinia wisi nobis, nulla purus luctus, id mi fermentum. Et suscipit,
                        nec maecenas, donec risus.
                        Corporis justo torquent, gravida phasellus, nec lacinia. Cras ut, viverra suspendisse. Netus sem,
                        placerat turpis, qui ut. A in. Lacinia wisi nobis, nulla purus luctus, id mi fermentum. Et suscipit,
                        nec maecenas, donec risus.
                    </p>

                    <button type="button" id="readMoreButton" class="read-more-button">Read More</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <main id="main">

            <!--Section A-->
            <section id="section-a" class="grid">
               //content
            </section>

            <!--Section B-->
            <section id="section-b" class="grid section-b-home-allign">
               //content
            </section>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

That sounds you haven’t included `jQuery` in your code. This is the only reason `$` would be undefined.

The easiest way to include it is to link to the CDN before your code in the script. The list of the links you need can be found here:

https://code.jquery.com